# How to not have the Welcome Message cached in Magento

Tags: magento, module

I'm trying to not have my "Welcome Message" on Magento Cart header cached by my full page cache module. Everything I've tried has led to complete failure. There has to be a way.

I'm using Magentos persistent cart option and I've discovered there is some difference in the welcome message with this option that the module developers may not have accounted for. Don't know really.

It's kind of like the "welcome message is it own module but in another way it's not, It's kind of a php one line on the header page.

Now my fpc module has an option in administration to exclude modules from being cached but you have to give the modules "name" You know i.e. name="some_name". The welcome message isn't like the rest of the other modules that I can tell. Here is the php in the header:

```
<p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getWelcome() ?> <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?></p>
```

There is nothing in the parentheses, so I've been trying to give this welcome message a name. I don't know how else to do it.

So I created a static block in adminisration with this in it:

```
{{block type="core/template" name"header.welcome" as="welcome" template="page/html/welcome.phtml"}}
```

Then I created a phtml file called welcome.phtml with this in it:

```
<p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getWelcome() ?> <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?></p>
```

Then in the header I added this:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('welcome')->toHTML(); ?>
```

That usually works with about anything. But not this time. Nothing. So under the block **page/html_header** I added this to page.xml:

```
<block type="core/template" name="header.welcome" as="welcome"/>
```

This is mt latest attempt. Does anyone have any ideas about how to go about this? I like the welcome message being dynamic.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The welcome message is just a function of the header block. Lesti_Fpc needs the welcome message in a seperated block. In Magento 1.8 this is solved and the name of the block is welcome. In Magento 1.7 there is a semi-solution in core...

This issue is solved here: (source)
https://gordonlesti.com/lestifpc-magento-1-7-and-the-welcome-message/

Answer (score -1):

I think I have made some progress for this problem.  However I am not getting the solution.  What I have done is created a new block in the app/design/frontend/default/layout/page.xml file.
I have added this:

```
<block type="page/html_welcome" name="testwelcome" as="testwelcome"/>
```

There seems to be a built in core function called "welcome".  It can be viewed at app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Welcome.php.  So That is the reference in the page.xml file.

Then in the header.phtml file in app/design/frontend/default/template/page.html I placed a call for:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('testwelcome') ?>
```

And finally I created a new template file called testwelcome.phtml in app/design/frontend/default/template with the following code:

```
<p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getWelcome() ?> <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?></p>
```

I can get the welcome message to display, but I can't seem to get it to render any changes.